# Carousel - loop - action per slide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Instead of a normal carousel I would like to use each slide as question.
Below each slide/question you need to have the option to answer.

Visual I have it working:

`demo`http://jsfiddle.net/surveydesigners/7wo1vx94/3/

I am using bootstrap + carousel slide option.
Not sure if the carousel is the correct option to achieve this.
But I need to save each answer to each slide/question.

Any ideas how to do this correctly?

```
                      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" data-wrap="false">


                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="carouseldiv1" id="c1">1/3<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="carouseldiv1" id="c2">2/3<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="carouseldiv1" id="c3">3/3<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="carouseldivend">All done - thank you!<br /><img src="icons/checkmr.png" width="16px" height="16px" /></div>
                    </div>                            
                  </div>


                      <div class="carouselcontrol">
                      <a href="#carousel-example-generic" id="answer1" role="button" data-slide="next" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">1</a>
                      <a href="#carousel-example-generic" id="answer2" role="button" data-slide="next" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">2</a>
                      <a href="#carousel-example-generic" id="answer3" role="button" data-slide="next" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">3</a>
                      <a href="#carousel-example-generic" id="answer4" role="button" data-slide="next" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">4</a>
                      <a href="#carousel-example-generic" id="answer5" role="button" data-slide="next" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">5</a>
                      <br /><br />
                      <a href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide-to="0" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">re-start</a>
                      </div>

                      <br />
                      <p class="txtmini">1 = totally agree || 5 = totally disagree</p>


                </div>
```

And then the code should be something like

```
IF C1 AND answer1 do ...
IF C1 AND answer2 do ...

IF C2 AND answer1 do ...
IF C2 AND answer2 do ...
etc.

$('#c1').click(function () { 
localStorage.setItem('C1', 'Answer1');      
localStorage.setItem('C2', 'Answer2');      
localStorage.setItem('C3', 'Answer3');      
localStorage.setItem('C4', 'Answer4');      
localStorage.setItem('C5', 'Answer5');
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I wouldn't necessarily look at it as something I have to use "carousel" for per se.... its primarily just a quiz type of situation, so you have:

1.) a JSON array of questions, each with objects for
2.) Answer Options
3.) Correct Answer

(note: if you use JSON to store your answers then it'll be visible to a user who views source code and can see all the javascript... so If its necessary, I might even store the answers in a web service where I send a post to get the answer back as a response then check if its correct or not.  But we'll just keep it simple for the sake of this particular use case).

So my questions would look like:

```
var myQuestions = [
    {"qCount": "1", "qText": "Why did Theon and Sansa Jump?", "qAnswers": "Answer1|Answer2|Answer3|Answer4", "qCorrectAnswer": "3"},
    {"qCount": "1", "qText": "Why did Theon and Sansa Jump?", "qAnswers": "Answer1|Answer2|Answer3|Answer4"},        {"qCount": "1", "qText": "Who is Reek?", "qAnswers": "Answer1|Answer2|Answer3|Answer4", "qCorrectAnswer": "1"},
    {"qCount": "1", "qText": "Did Brienne kill Stannis?", "qAnswers": "Answer1|Answer2|Answer3|Answer4", "qCorrectAnswer": "2"}
];
```

Now I just use jQuerys .each to loop and display each question, use split to display the answer options as LI items beneath the question and compare the index (position) of the clicked item with the qCorrectAnswer value (which is intended to correspond the the position of the correct answer after we split based on the | character).

After the results of their selection are displayed I'd store their answer (I'd probably  use cookie instead of local storage (mainly because I had a recent horror story trying to use local storage in an app, just my lack of knowledge Im willing to bet)).   and after a few seconds, replace the currently displayed question and answer options with the NEXT set in the JSON array.   Prior to displaying the NEXT one though, I'll check to see if we've reached the LAST question, and if we have then I'll break the cycle and show some END UI elements / info.

So forcing it to be a carousel MIGHT be making it harder to do, the way I have it framed in my mind (noting that I just may not be in tune with your reasoning for using carousel concept) its relatively simple to implement and using your own jQuery gives you more flexibility.  Good luck with it.

update:  heres a crude (unfinished) fiddle example of how I MIGHT approach it... very very rough and unfinished.  [http://jsfiddle.net/tamak/nvbeLxx5/7/]

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late response.
thanks for the answer - although it is a little bit different I think this can work for me as well - many thanks for providing this!!